# Javascript comma between seconds

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I'm trying to fix this but I can't figure out where I need to start. I using an timer for a banner to play a game and the timer is in seconds with 4 digits. Now, I would like to have a comma between the seconds so it look like this: 13,80 instead of this: 1380. How can I make sure there will be a comma in the seconds?

Here is my code:

```
var x = new clsStopwatch();
var $time;
var clocktimer;

function pad(num, size) {
    var s = "0000" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length - size);
}

function formatTime(time) {
    var s = ms = 0;
    var newTime = '';

    time = time % (60 * 60 * 1000);
    m = Math.floor( time / (60 * 1000) );
    time = time % (24 * 1000);
    s = Math.floor( time / 45 + 3800);

     newTime =  pad(s,4) ;
         return newTime;
```

Comment: what is 13,80? s, ms, time, m, or newTime? what is pad()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this:

```
var str = 1234;
console.log(str.substr(0,2)+','+str.substr(2)); //will print 12,34
```

Ur code will become:

```
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = "0000" + num;
    var str = s.substr(s.length - size);
    return str.substr(0,2)+','+str.substr(2);
}
```

Comment: Inside ur  function pad(num, size) {
    var s = "0000" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length - size);
}              ??

Comment: glad to hear that :) !

Answer (score 0):

```
var myNumber = 123;
var myArray = myNumber.toString().split(""); // ["1", "2", "3"]
while (myArray.length < 4) {
    myArray.unshift("0"); // ["0", "1", "2", "3"];
}
myArray.splice(2, 0, ","); // second position, take none out, insert comma
// ["0, "1", ",", "2", "3"];
console.log(myArray.join("")); // myArray.join("") === "01,23"
```

Comment: `unshift()` and `shift()` same as `push()` / `pop()`. `slice()` and `splice()` are opposite in almost all ways. you should definitely check out all of the array functions though, most of my interview questions require an array, especially as a queue or stack. strings are primitive, arrays can have contents modified, and base functions for the Array are written in C, so they're generally fast. shift unshift are slower because you edit the index of all numbers, it's order N, but indexes keep arrays way faster than objects

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but it works

```
//takes a number
//e.g. 9104 returns 91,04
function addComma(number){
    var frm = String(number);
    return number > 99 ? frm.substring(0, frm.length-2) + ',' + frm.substring(frm.length-2, frm.length) : "0," + frm
}
```